# How to use await in a python lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: await somefunction(x))
```

But I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

Which makes sense because the lambda is not async.

I tried to use `async lambda x: ...` but that throws  a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

[Pep 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#async-lambda-functions) states:

> Syntax for asynchronous lambda functions could be provided, but this construct is outside of the scope of this PEP.

But I could not find out if that syntax was implemented in CPython.

Is there a way to declare an async lambda, or to use an async function for sorting a list?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can't.  There is no `async lambda`, and even if there were, you coudln't pass it in as key function to `list.sort()`, since a key function will be called as a synchronous function and not awaited.  An easy work-around is to annotate your list yourself:

```py
mylist_annotated = [(await some_function(x), x) for x in mylist]
mylist_annotated.sort()
mylist = [x for key, x in mylist_annotated]
```

Note that `await` expressions in list comprehensions are only supported in Python 3.6+. If you're using 3.5, you can do the following:

```py
mylist_annotated = []
for x in mylist:
    mylist_annotated.append((await some_function(x), x)) 
mylist_annotated.sort()
mylist = [x for key, x in mylist_annotated]
```

Comment: I was getting a `SyntaxError: 'await' expressions in comprehensions are not supported`, so i had to do this (for future reference):

    mylist_annotated = []
    for x in mylist:
        mylist_annotated.append((await some_function(x), x))
    mylist_annotated.sort()
    mylist = [x for key, x in mylist_annotated]

And now it works, thanks!

Comment: @iCart Right, that's a restriction in Python 3.5, which is lifted in the upcoming Python 3.6.

Comment: Found a very edge case - see my answer :-)

Comment: This is called a "Schwartzian Transform"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 36):

An "`async` `lambda`" can be emulated by combining a `lambda` with an `async` generator:<sup>1</sup>

```py
key=lambda x: (await somefunction(x) for _ in '_').__anext__()
```

It is possible to move the `(   ).__anext__()` to a helper, which likely makes the pattern clearer as well:

```py
def head(async_iterator): return async_iterator.__anext__()

key=lambda x: head(await somefunction(x) for _ in '_')
```

Note that the sort method/function in the standard library are not async. One needs an async version, such as [`asyncstdlib.sorted`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/builtins.html#asyncstdlib.builtins.sorted) (disclaimer: I maintain this library):

```py
import asyncstdlib as a

mylist = await a.sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: head(await somefunction(x) for _ in '_'))
```

---

#### Understanding the `lambda ...: (...).__anext__()` pattern

An "`async` `lambda`" would be an anonymous asynchronous function, or in other words an anonymous function evaluating to an awaitable. This is in parallel to how `async def` defines a named function evaluating to an awaitable.
The task can be split into two parts: An *anonymous function expression* and a nested *awaitable expression*.

- An anonymous function expression is exactly what a `lambda ...: ...` is.
- An awaitable expression [is only allowed inside a coroutine function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#await-expression); however:

  - An (asynchronous) generator expression implicitly creates a (coroutine) function. As an async generator only needs async to run, it can be *defined* in a sync function ([since Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)).
  - An asynchronous iterable can be used as an awaitable via its [`__anext__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#asynchronous-generator-iterator-methods).

These three parts are directly used in the "`async` `lambda`" pattern:

```py
#   | regular lambda for the callable and scope
#   |         | async generator expression for an async scope
#   v         v                                    v first item as an awaitable
key=lambda x: (await somefunction(x) for _ in '_').__anext__()
```

The `for _ in '_'` in the async generator is only to have exactly one iteration. Any variant with at least one iteration will do.

---

<sup>1</sup>Be mindful whether an "`async` `lambda`" is actually needed in the first place, since async functions are first class just like regular functions. Just as `lambda x: foo(x)` is redundant and should just be `foo`, `lambda x: (await bar(x) …)` is redundant and should just be `bar` . The function body should do more than just call-and-`await`, such as `3 + await bar(x)` or `await bar(x) or await qux(x)`.

Comment: This is both beautiful and a bit disturbing at the same time!  Is there some way of using this syntax to create a lambda equivalent to `async def foo(): return None`?  I tried `lambda : (None for _ in "_").__anext__()`, but this didn't work.

Comment: @FrankYellin I'm afraid the trick only works if there is *something* async to do. For simple "return a constant" cases I would recommend writing a utility function.

Comment: Thanks anyway. A utility function is probably more readable anyway. But I had to ask.

Comment: In my case, I'm using higher order functions for dispatch or other things where I can't know which function will be called. As said in the footnote, async functions are first class and, indeed, almost indistinguishable from sync functions. One can make a "thunk" with `lambda` which returns _the call result_ of an async function--in other words, the coroutine. That coroutine can then be `await`ed as normal. Eg: `await (lambda: foo_async(a, b, c))()` will work just fine. I don't think this would be useful for OP's case specifically, but this SO is the top result for "python async lambda", so...

Comment: @pyansharp I am hoping the footnote makes that clear. Let me know if the surgeon of the footnote or the answer could be improved to that effect.

Answer (score 10):

`await` cannot be included in a `lambda` function.

The solutions here can be shortened to:

```python
from asyncio import coroutine, run


my_list = [. . .]


async def some_function(x) -> coroutine:
    . . .

my_list.sort(key=lambda x: await some_function(x))  # raises a SyntaxError
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: run(some_function(x))  # works
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already defined a separate async function, you can simplify MisterMiyagi's answer even a bit more:

```
mylist = await a.sorted(
    mylist, 
    key=somefunction)
```

If you want to change the key *after* awaiting it, you can use [asyncstdlib.apply](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/asynctools.html#asyncstdlib.asynctools.apply):

```
mylist = await a.sorted(
    mylist, 
    key=lambda x: a.apply(lambda after: 1 / after, some_function(x)))
```

Here is a complete example program:

```
import asyncio
import asyncstdlib as a

async def some_function(x):
    return x

async def testme():
    mylist=[2, 1, 3]

    mylist = await a.sorted(
        mylist, 
        key=lambda x: a.apply(lambda after: 1 / after, some_function(x)))
        
    print(f'mylist is: {mylist}')
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(testme())
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Sven Marnach has an Edge case.

If you try and sort a list that has 2 items that produce the same search key but are different and are not directly sortable, it will crash.

```
mylist = [{'score':50,'name':'bob'},{'score':50,'name':'linda'}]

mylist_annotated = [(x['score'], x) for x in mylist]
mylist_annotated.sort()
print( [x for key, x in mylist_annotated] )
```

Will give:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Fortunately I had an easy solution - my data had a unique key in that was sortable, so I could put that as the second key:

```
mylist = [{'score':50,'name':'bob','unique_id':1},{'score':50,'name':'linda','unique_id':2}]

mylist_annotated = [(x['score'], x['unique_id'], x) for x in mylist]
mylist_annotated.sort()
print( [x for key, unique, x in mylist_annotated] )
```

I guess if your data doesn't have a naturally unique value in, you can insert one before trying to sort? A uuid maybe?

**EDIT**: As suggested in comment (Thanks!), you can also use operator.itemgetter:

```
import operator

mylist = [{'score':50,'name':'bob'},{'score':50,'name':'linda'}]

mylist_annotated = [(x['score'], x) for x in mylist]
mylist_annotated.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
print( [x for key, x in mylist_annotated] )
```

Comment: I think the best solution for this edge case would be to pass `operator.itemgetter(0)` as key function to `sort()`. Tuples are sorted lexicographically, so equal keys will result in a comparison of the second item. By explicitly selecting only the first item as the sort key we prevent that second comparison.