# Python: How to call async function inside rx.subject subscribe on_next

Tags: python, async-await, reactive-programming, python-asyncio, rx-py

I need to call an async function inside the `on_next` of a python `rx` subscription as this:

```py
from rx.subject import Subject
import asyncio

async def asyncPrint(value: str):
    print(f'async print: {value}')


async def main():
    s = Subject()
    s.subscribe(
        on_error=lambda e: print(e),
        on_next=lambda value: asyncPrint(value)
    )
    s.on_next('Im from the subject')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

but I get the async error:

```
$ python test.py 
rx\core\observer\autodetachobserver.py:26:
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'asyncPrint' was never awaited
  self._on_next(value)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I really don't want to use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(...)` because I'm already running the main loop and I don't want to start a new one neither use nested loops.

I searched a about it and I saw that a `lambda` function [can't be async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746213/how-to-use-await-in-a-python-lambda). And I think maybe that's the problem here, because I really don't know how to get the `on_next` value without a lambda funtion using `rx` library.

I also searched about [async-rx](https://pypi.org/project/async-rx/) library, but this looks like the only different thing that can be done is an `await subscribe(...)`, but that's not what I want. I want something like `subscribe(on_next=await...)`.

Is that possible? from my `javascript` background its easy to start a `async` function inside a `subscribe` so it looks like a possible task for me. Hope someone could find a solution to that.

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

finally I manage to make this work by using `asyncio.run_task()`

```
from rx.subject import Subject
import asyncio

async def asyncPrint(value: str):
    print(f'async print: {value}')

async def main():
    s = Subject()
    s.subscribe(
        on_error=lambda e: print(e),
        on_next=lambda value: asyncio.create_task(asyncPrint(value))
    )
    s.on_next('Im from the subject')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

output:

```sh
$ python teste.py 
async print: Im from the subject
```