# Async lambda function in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm building a bot with discord.py and i have encountered a problem with lambda and async.
In particular i don't know how to fit a "Async lambda", if it possible, in the play function.
This is the actual code:

```
async def play(...):
    ...
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(source=self.song_path), 
               after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))

async def play_next(...):
    ...
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
            source=self.song_path),
            after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
    await ctx.send(embed=Utility.get_embed("Now Playing", self.song_queue))
```

And this is the problem

> coroutine 'main_bot.play_next' was never awaited
> self.after(error)
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback*

EDIT: [working answer in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329179/async-lambda-function-in-discord-py?noredirect=1#comment119008145_67329179)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use await in a python lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746213/how-to-use-await-in-a-python-lambda)

Comment: Take a look at [How do I pass a coroutine to the player’s after function?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-pass-a-coroutine-to-the-player-s-after-function)