# Can i use await into a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, async-await, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot with discord API for python, but I'm having a problem:

```
    async def nextSong(self):
        if not self.loop:
            self.queue.pop(0)
            self.name.pop(0)

        if len(self.queue) >= 1:
            await self.playSong(self.ctx, self.queue[0], self.name[0])

        elif len(self.queue) == 0:
            print("There are no more songs")

    async def playSong(self, ctx, link, name):
        self.ctx = ctx
        # x = (await self.nextSong())
        ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(link, **self.ffmpeg_options),
                              after=lambda l:
                              await self.nextSong())
        ctx.voice_client.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(ctx.voice_client.source)
        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = 0.50
        em = discord.Embed(title="Queue", description=("You are listening to " + name))
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

I'can't transform these two functions into synchronized function because I'm using "await ctx.send"

output:

```
    await self.nextSong())
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use await in a python lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746213/how-to-use-await-in-a-python-lambda)

Comment: The solutions given to this question did not work

Comment: No, you can't use `await` inside a lambda expression